# vaadin 7.75 How to add combobox to a grid?

Tags: java, vaadin

I'm on Vaadin 7.7 and I switch tables to the grid. Only I can not personalize my cells as I would like. Here I would like to add comboboxes on a column from an arraylist and retrieve the chosen value.

Here's some of my code:

Here I create my IndexedContainer

```
  IndexedContainer indexedContainer = new IndexedContainer();
  indexedContainer.addContainerProperty("Type de véhicule",String.class,"");
```

Here I add my items:

```
    indexedContainer.addItem(listValue);
    indexedContainer.getContainerProperty(listValue,
            key.get(0)).setValue(
            String.valueOf(listValue.get(0)));
```

Finally I put my object in editable and I use this function to do actions during the backup:

```
grid.getEditorFieldGroup().addCommitHandler(new FieldGroup.CommitHandler() {
    @Override
    public void preCommit(FieldGroup.CommitEvent commitEvent) throws FieldGroup.CommitException {

    }
    @Override
    public void postCommit(FieldGroup.CommitEvent commitEvent) throws FieldGroup.CommitException {
```

If you have any ideas or suggestions do not hesitate :)

Good night

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
List<String> values = obtainValues();
IndexedContainer container = new IndexedContainer();
//Add other properties...
container.addContainerProperty("comboBox", ComboBox.class, null);
//Do more stuff
ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
cb.addItems(values);
item.getItemProperty("comboBox").setValue(cb);
```

And, in grid declaration, you may use an [addon](https://vaadin.com/directory/#!addon/componentrenderer) that allows grid to render components.

```
Grid grid = new Grid();
//Even more stuff
grid.setContainerDataSource(container);
grid.getColumn("comboBox").setRenderer(new ComponentRenderer());
```

To obtain the value of the comboBox:

```
Item item = container.getItem(itemId);
ComboBox cb = item.getItemProperty("comboBox").getValue();
String value = (String) cb.getValue();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
grid.getColumn("state").setEditorField(getComboState());
```

where getComboState is:

```
private Field<?> getComboState() {
    ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox();
    comboBox.addItem("approve");
    comboBox.addItem("no-approve");
    comboBox.setImmediate(true);
    comboBox.setNullSelectionAllowed(false);
    return  comboBox;
}
```