# How to make vaadin table cell click listener

Tags: java, tooltip, vaadin, clicklistener

I have vaadin table with some rows and columns in it. How can I make the cells to be clickable of 1 particular column?

Goal : Instead of mouse hover, I want to show the tool tip on the click of the cell of that 1 particular column. The cell contains text as label.

I am not posting any code as all I have is just table (which wont help anyone).

Comment: Wich version of Vaadin are you using?

Comment: I am using vaadin 7.7.10

Comment: You may use what the say here https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-grid/issues/407 They told that cells by itself cannot be clicked, but you can add a component inside them that is, solving your problem.

Comment: thanks, though i was able to solve my issue by using "labelButton" addon, making content of each cell as label, which are clickable. But I also agree with your solution as I did use that in other project. Can you please post it as the answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently is not possible to have a `clickListener` attached to a particular cell in a `Grid`, as adressed on this [discussion](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-grid/issues/407). They told that cells are just representations of data, not elements, so they cannot be clicked.

Instead of that, you can add a component inside a cell like the addon `LabelButton` ([github](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-grid/issues/407)) or simply add a `Button` and style it to be borderless.

***PD: As a bonus, I'm adding the code to add `Button` in `Grid`:***

**Vaadin 7**

```
RendererClickListener clickListener = new RendererClickListener() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void click(RendererClickEvent event) {
        //Do your actions
    }
};
ButtonRenderer renderer = new ButtonRenderer(ownerClickListener, "");
grid.getColumn("columnName").setRenderer(renderer);
```

An alternative to this approach would be use a property generator like `GeneratedPropertyContainer` and use an addon like `ComponentRenderer` ([here](https://vaadin.com/directory/#!addon/componentrenderer)) to render buttons. An example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44310660/vaadin-7-75-how-to-add-combobox-to-a-grid/45278156#45278156) in other of my answers..

**Vaadin 8.1**

Vaadin 8.1 now has a built-in `ComponentRenderer` for use in `Grid`. See [*What’s New*](https://vaadin.com/framework/whatsnew), first item, “Components in Grid”.

```
grid.addComponentColumn(person -> {
    Button button = new Button("Click me!");
    button.addClickListener(click ->
        Notification.show("Clicked: " + person.toString()));
    return button;
});
// make sure the buttons fit in the cells of the Grid
grid.setBodyRowHeight(40);
```

As the example showed in `Grid` documentation [in Vaadin page](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-grid.html)

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to Vaadin, and I'm finding out that there are major changes between the releases, and you need to do some digging to find solutions.

Comment: @MattC If you liked the answer, think about upvoting it.